# What is the proper way to deal with deep recursion in boost::spirit::qi grammar?

Tags: c++, recursion, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have a working grammar similar to the following:

```
stock_price = symbol_ >> date_ >> price_;
stock_prices_ = stock_price_ >> stock_prices_ | eps;
grammar_ = lit( "PRICES" ) >> stock_prices_ >> lit( "END" );
```

The problem is, when the list of stock prices_ gets too high (say around 1000 prices), the the parses seg-faults with a exc_bad_access. I can actually solve this by:

```
stock_prices_ = stock_price_ >> stock_price_ >> stock_price_ >> stock_price >> stock_prices_ |
                stock_price_ >> stock_prices_ |
                eps;
```

but I don't see this as an elegant solution. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Maybe go exponential on the probelm.  20 exponential patterns would restrict recursion depth to about 40 + 1 per million.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be completely missing the problem here, but what wrong with the [kleene star](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/kleene.html), [plus parser](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/plus.html) and or [list parser directive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/list.html)s?

```
stock_prices_ = +stock_price_ | eps; // one or more stock_price_ or nothing
```

However, this looks to be exactly the semantics of just kleene star:

```
stock_price = symbol_ >> date_ >> price_;
grammar_    = "PRICES" >> *stock_price_ >> "END"; // zero or more stock_price_
```

Now, if you wanted them line-separated e.g., use<sup>[1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/kleene.html)</sup>:

```
grammar_    = "PRICES" >> -(stock_price_ % eol) >> "END";
```

---

<sup>[1](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/kleene.html)</sup> combine with e.g. the `qi::blank` skipper, which doesn't eat the newlines

Comment: Thanks! This was pretty obvious, and I just didn't think of it. Fairly new to implementing grammars.

Comment: @statguy Cheers :) I venture that _either_ you come from a functional programming background, _or_ you might like the paradigm :) Using recursion over iteration is paramount in pure functional programming.